# Convert excel formula to php

Tags: php, excel, formula

I rent out caravans and am looking to offer pay monthly options.

We have worked out a formula in **Excel** but need to convert it to PHP.

**The excel formula is:**

```
monthlyCost=SUM("holidayCost"/(roundDown(((("holDate"-30)-"todaysDate")/30),0)))
```

The problem is rounding the number down.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you're unaware of PHP's [round()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function and its `mode` argument

Answer (score 2):

`round((( $holDate - 30 - $todaysDate)/30), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);`

Comment: Many thanks. Where in the formula will the holiday price be?

Comment: this just for the round part. Could you put a example with sample values of what the result  of the formula should be ?

Comment: Example 1
Holiday Price = £400
Holiday Date = 1/7/2014
Monthly Cost = £100

Example 2
Holiday Price = £400
Holiday Date = 22/7/2014
Monthly Cost = £80

Example 2 is reduced as there is an extra month of payments due to the round down.

Hope this helps.

Adam